# Typescript: create external module from internal module

Tags: typescript

I currently have an internal module defined in `foo.ts` (edit: that can't be modified)

```
module Foo {
    export function foo(){
        console.log('foo');
    }
}
```

that I want to transform in an external module (to use in Node). So I created a `bar.ts` where I reference `foo.ts` and then I try to export it.

```
/// <reference path='foo.ts' />

export = Foo;
```

When I compile it using `tsc -m commonjs --out bundle.js bar.ts` I expect it to concatenate the declaration from `foo.ts` and then the export from `bar.ts`. However I get `foo.ts` and `bar.ts` compiled but separated and then `bundle.js` only has the same code as `foo.js`.

```
var Foo;
(function (Foo) {
    function foo() {
        console.log('foo');
    }
    Foo.foo = foo;
})(Foo || (Foo = {}));
```

Is this even possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this can't be done using the `export` keyword of Typescript. The solution is (using the same foo.ts) use this `bar.ts`

```
/// <reference path="foo.ts" />

exports = Foo; // You will need node.d.ts
```

which gets compiled to a bundle of `foo.ts` and `bar.ts`. Bad news is that you lose the ability to (easily) create AMD and CommonJS modules with the same source (i.e. using `export`).

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
module Foo {
    export function foo(){
        console.log('foo');
    }
}
```

With:

```
export function foo(){
    console.log('foo');
}
```

Root file level `export` or `import` statements identify a file as an external module.

Comment: The problem is that I would prefer not to modify the original declaration. I can do it now cause it's my project but what if it's a foreign project I've just cloned?